# Creating multi graph using multiple JSON array datasets

Tags: javascript, json, svg, d3.js

I'm learning D3 and as a sandbox example I'm trying to create a multi line graph but I don't want to use CSV, TSV or anything similar.

The key portion is at the bottom where I'm basically doing iterating over an array of the datasets (which themselves are arrays of objects {data:blah, price:bleh}.

And I'm trying to append each dataset to the inner svg space.

The problem is that after the first dataset, each subsequent dataset will append to the right and go very far out of my svg container and I obviously want it to stay inside the same SVG space
[image: dataChart]

A lot of these functions are for helping me manage these randomly generated datasets.
For my data I'm using:
momentjs, underscorejs, and obviously d3js

```
var margin, width, height, parseDate, xScale, yScale, xAxis, yAxis, valueLine, nextDay,
    dataSet1, dataSet2, dataSet3, dataSet4, innerSpace;
function tlate(x, y){return 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')';}
function day(){
    var today = moment().subtract(1, 'year')
    return function(){
        return moment( today.add(1, 'day') );
    }
}
nextDay = day();

function randomPrice(){
    return _.random(125, 200);
}

function minDay(arr){
    var minimum = moment( moment().add(100, 'years') );
    _.each(arr, function(elem){
        minimum = moment.min(minimum, elem.date)
    })
    return minimum;
}

function maxDay(arr){
    var maximum = moment( moment().subtract(100, 'years') );
    _.each(arr, function(elem){
        maximum = moment.max(maximum, elem.date)
    })
    return maximum;
}

function minOfMultiple(arr, key){
    var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    _.each(arr, function(dataSet){
        _.each(dataSet, function(element){
            min = _.min([min, element[key]])
        })
    })
    return min;
}

function maxOfMultiple(arr, key){
    var max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    _.each(arr, function(dataSet){
        _.each(dataSet, function(element){
            max = _.max([max, element[key]])
        })
    })
    return max;
}


function createDataSet(){
    return [
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()},
        {date: nextDay(), price: randomPrice()}
    ];
}

dataSet1 = createDataSet();
dataSet2 = createDataSet();
dataSet3 = createDataSet();
dataSet4 = createDataSet();

//increased bottom margin so as to give room for rotated x labels
margin = { top: 30, right:20, bottom: 30, left: 50 };
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right;
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


//parse date and time
parseDate = d3.time.format('%b %Y').parse;


//set ranges
xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width])
yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])

//axis
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(xScale)
                .orient('bottom')
                .ticks(5)

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(yScale)
                .orient('left')
                .ticks(5)


priceLine = d3.svg.line()
                    .x(function(d){ return xScale(d.date) })
                    .y(function(d){ return yScale(d.price) })



//add svg canvas and select innerSpace
innerSpace = d3.select('body').append('svg')
                                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.bottom)
                                .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                            .append('g')
                                .attr('transform', tlate(margin.left, margin.top))


//setting number domains
xScale.domain( [ minDay(dataSet1), maxDay(dataSet1) ] )
yScale.domain( [0,  maxOfMultiple([dataSet1,dataSet2,dataSet3,dataSet4], 'price')] )

_.each([dataSet1,dataSet2,dataSet3,dataSet4], function(ds){
    innerSpace.append('path')
                .attr('class', 'line')
                .attr('d', priceLine(ds))

})
```

Answer (score 0):

My helper function was extending the dates past the range intended.